# 'Tuple is not callable' in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got error in Python while trying to plot something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(list_x,list_y)
```

As I mentioned in title this error is:

```
'tuple' object is not callable
```

I was wondering what's wrong with my code, but then I realized that this error appears even when I'm pasting correct code (for example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/accented_text.html ).

This is weird. Thanks for advance for any helping tips.

Comment: Is this all of the code? Maybe you are shading the function earlier..?

Comment: At the very least, you should post the whole traceback (the entire error message, not just the last line); and you should probably post more of your code.

Comment: It looks like your import didn't work properly. It doesn't seem like 'plt' is seen as a module but a tuple. Try 'help(plt)' or 'print(plt)' . If you run print, you should get:<module 'matplotlib.pyplot' from 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc'> or something similar. I would try to reinstall matplotlib.

Comment: If that is the offending line, it means that plt.plot is the tuple. That would be weird. Paste the full traceback, so we can know what is happening, and also how you got matplotlib and python installed.

Comment: Obviously this isn't _all_ the code since list_x and list_y are not defined here. Can you show a complete session where this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you may have accidentally overwritten the value of `plt.plot`

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:37:08) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot
<function plot at 0x2285488>
```

If the problem persists in a new interpreter, you should see what the tuple is that `plt.plot` displays. Maybe that is a clue to what has gone wrong.