# Matplotlib plt.plot() not working in anaconda

Tags: python

I tried to run this code in spyder IDE of anaconda but it's not working

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5],[1,4,9,16,25])
plt.show()
```

The above code is returning error as follows:
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

I am not able to figure out the problem.Please help

Comment: Could you include the complete error traceback in your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762481/tuple-is-not-callable-in-python this may be related, can't tell without you posting more of the error.

Comment: Try `print(plt.plot)`. If it says `tuple` then you've accidentally assigned the function name to a `tuple`. You need to reload the library or restart your kernel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Tuple is not callable' in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762481/tuple-is-not-callable-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Builtin function not working with Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738537/builtin-function-not-working-with-spyder)

Comment: Ok, it's not a builtin but I'm 99.9% confident that it's the same issue. I also link to a way how to stop this happening in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies here but I had similar issues with matplotlib. From another Stackoverflow-answer this suggestion helped me:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

As said in the comments: the full error would help figuring out what really goes wrong.